# Nuxt JS Login route is still accessible after successful login

Tags: vuejs2, middleware, nuxt.js

I am trying to resolve this issue past few weeks. I followed couple of series. One on youtube, and one on codecourse. Both of them showed the right way to authenticate user, but once the user is logged in. Login route is still accessible. I will try to give as much information i can.

This is my nuxt.config.js

```
 auth: {
    plugins: ["~plugins/auth.js"],
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: "auth/login",
            method: "post",
            propertyName: "meta.token"
          },
          user: {
            url: "auth/me",
            method: "get",
            propertyName: "data"
          },
          logout: {
            url: "auth/logout",
            method: "post"
          },
          redirect: {
            login: "/auth/login",
            logout: "/",
            home: "/",
            callback: "/"
          },
          watchLoggedIn: true,
          rewriteRedirects: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Here is my login.vue

```
export default {
  middleware: ["guest"],
  auth: "guest",
  name: "login",
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        email: "",
        password: ""
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async login() {
      await this.$auth.loginWith("local", {
        data: this.form
      });
      this.$router.push({
        path: this.$route.query.redirect || "/dashboard"
      });
    }
  }
};
```

It's still accessible after login.

Answer (score -1):

Your configured it wrong. Its all described in the docs. For example [middleware](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/middleware.html)

There is no such thing as

```
middleware: ["guest"],
```

as in your code. Middleware called auth as you can see in docs. So you need to set it either

> Setting per route:
>
> ```
> export default {
>   middleware: 'auth'
> }
> ```
>
> Globally setting in nuxt.config.js:
>
> ```
> router: {
>   middleware: ['auth']
> }
> ```

Comment: I guess, you didn't follow what i said. I found a guidance on youtube tutorial. Which is where i created guest middleware.

Comment: @manshu if u created your guest middleware u need to add it to the post. There is noone know what u followed and what u did. U need to provide all relevant code otherwise its as good as nothing. Nowhere in your post u said u have created guest middleware yourself